# How to stop till an action is done to perform the next action?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app i have a music player which actually the song from iTunes and plays preview.
But as the AVAudio player requires the file to be written in a local file to play it. So at times its taking 2-3 seconds after i click my play button so i wanted to show a UIActivityIndicator view on my button so the user knows its loading.

I know how to do it for other view loading but here its all happening inside a single method one after another so don't know how to do this.

Here's my code:

```
wait = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        UIView * temp = (UIView *)sender;
        [temp addSubview:wait];
        [wait startAnimating];
        NSError * error;
        int tag = [sender tag]-100;
        previousTag = sender;
        active = sender;
        UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
        [UIView transitionWithView:button
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                        animations:^{ 
                            [button setBackgroundImage:pauseButtonImage.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }
                        completion:NULL];
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tag inSection:0];
        [songsResults selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

        NSString * floatPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"preview%d",tag];
        NSString *uniquePath = [TMP stringByAppendingPathComponent: floatPath];
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: uniquePath])
            {
                [wait stopAnimating];
                audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:uniquePath] error:&error];
            }
            else {

            NSArray * temp = [dataToDisplay objectAtIndex:tag];
            NSString * urlString = [temp objectAtIndex:3];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

            [soundData writeToFile:uniquePath atomically:YES];
                [wait stopAnimating];
            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:uniquePath] error:&error];
            }
        float duration = [audioPlayer duration];

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration target:self selector:@selector(stopPreview:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            [audioPlayer play];
            isPlaying = YES;
    }
```

Comment: "its all happening inside a single method", that's the problem right there. Separate the responsibilities and you'lll get more flexibility. your single method is responsible for too many tasks.

Comment: Ok but still should i just do performSelectorOnMainThread: untilDone??

Comment: You'll have to do something like the answer below. The gui, in this case the wait indicator, won't update until the function completes. You'll have to do the work in a separate function on a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the blocking task to run in the background by calling `performSelectorInBackground`. and in order to be notified when the task is done, either pass a block or use a delegate.

FileStorage.h

```
@protocol FileStorageDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)fileStorageDidWriteToFile;
@end

@interface FileStorage

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FileStorageDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

FileStorage.m

```
@implementation FileStorage
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)storeFile:(NSData *)data
{
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(storeFileInBackground:) withObject:data];
}

- (void)storeFileInBackground:(NSData *)data
{
   // perfofm blocking task


   // Call delegate and pass some parameters if needed
   [self.delegate fileStorageDidWriteToFile];
}

@end
```